# Oracle Apex - set value = dates

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with a drop down P10_QUARTER_DD (submits page on selection), with year quarters like this:

```
Q1
Q2
Q3
Q4
```

(display and return values are the same)
This drop down sets the value of an item on change:

```
display_only_item_1

select
case
    when :P10_QUARTER_DD = 'Q1' then to_date('06/01/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    when :P10_QUARTER_DD = 'Q2' then to_date('09/01/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    when :P10_QUARTER_DD = 'Q3' then to_date('12/01/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    when :P10_QUARTER_DD = 'Q4' then to_date('03/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    else null
end quarter
from dual
```

When selecting (for example) Q2 I get the following value on my display item:
9/1/2022

Anybody knows how to fix this? how to get a proper date value?
(I'll use this value for Interactive Report filtering)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the display only item's [format mask](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmdb/applying-format-masks-to-items.html#GUID-915C7168-FB4C-474A-8083-6FC966E53C0D) attribute as MM/DD/YYYY.
The query and the date format on your query, sets the items session value. How it is displayed on the page, can be set by format masking.